# Mac randomly stopping Internet

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I'm really kind of clueless as to what is going on here, but it is really becoming frustrating. I haven't ever came across this issue on any other Macs, and it seems to be unique to me for some reason. So what happens is my computer will be connected to the internet and wifi just fine, and then sometimes my mac seems to have just **randomly dropped** connection to the internet. The **wifi bars are all full**, and the other computers in the house seem to be working fine during that period. However, for me I have to *restart* my computer to actually get the internet on the computer to begin working again, and it is ok once or twice but this occurs once or twice every day which is beginning to get frustrating.

*Please Note: I am kind of confused about what could possibly  be going on, so I would be more than happy to provide information such as system logs, etc. But just ask.. I don't want to just dump potentially irrelevant information into the question.*

Comment: Feel free to ping me on the next question - just @bmke here or in my answer and a link to what you found using the diagnostics.

Comment: Have you tried turning the wifi on/off instead of restarting the computer? Happens to me on the school network and I find that restarting the wifi works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Good call on not dumping the kitchen sink. The first step is to run **Network  Diagnostics** - once when things work so you can see what it does and again when things are broken.

It will guide you through changes to make, so keep a short log of when you run it and what it has green/yellow/red and what changes are needed to fix each breakage.

Over time, you'll probably find a pattern to one thing breaking and can ask a more narrow follow up question.

To run the tool:

1. Open Finder
2. Use the Go manu - Go to folder
3. paste in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`
4. Drag Network Diagnostics to your dock so it's easy to access

You can also use the "assist me" button in network settings - it's bottom right next to apply:

[image]

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21585

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I will check this out and notify you of the results the next time my computer decides to drop connections.

Comment: Also, on a side note when I click "Assist me" I choose "Diagnostics" and then I select "Wifi". Now since everything is working I get the message "Your Internet Connection appears to be working correctly" which is expected.

Comment: Ok, so it did it again. The Internet stopped working, and I went to Network Diagnostics. For some reason, the ISP, Internet, and Server were all showing a red indicator. Then, I chose Wifi, and chose my Wifi Network's name and then it turned every indicator to green, and my Internet started working again. Why is that the case?